# PHP не работает require и аналогичные функции

Tags: php, хостинг

Зарегистрировался на бесплатном хостинге byethost.com. Функции типа require('text.html') - работают, а вот require('..app/text.html') нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такое может быть?
Папка app создана, на нее и все ее содержимое стоят права 777. Это же код на локальном сервере работает.

**update** возможно  как-то заблокированы инклуды из других папок?

Comment: не важно в чем тут проблема, никогда не пишите пути таким образом, лучше всего указывать полный путь, т.е. что-то типа

     require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/someDirectory/someFile.someExt';

Comment: 1. Так не работает тоже.
2. Наличие скобок же не критично ?
3. А так можно ? require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/someDirectory/someFile.someExt';

Comment: могут быть заблокированы права предыдущей директории на чтение.

Comment: стоят права 777

Answer (score 2):

Не забывайте про слешы!

вместо:

```
require('..app/text.html')
```

нужно:

```
require('../app/text.html')
```

P.S: Для home/dir1/test.php это означает подключение home/app/text.html... Уверены-ли вы, в таком пути?

UPD: А какие права на родительскую ( "../" ) папку?

Comment: В пути уверен. Слеш как раз нужен т.к. слеш у последней папки в пути ОС не ставит и получится  homeapp/text.html , а не  home/app/text.html

Comment: Вы слово "стоит" не с тем ударением прочитали...

Comment: А какие права на родительскую ( "../" ) папку? - не знаю). И как посмотреть не знаю. Это же бесплатный хостинг

Comment: >В пути уверен. Слеш как раз нужен т.к. слеш у последней папки в пути >ОС не ставит и получится homeapp/text.html , а не home/app/text.html

та сам это придумал?

Comment: Почти . Просто все функции в PHP, которыми я пользовался возвращают строку вида '/dir/dir/dir' - без последнего слеша

Comment: > Слеш как раз нужен т.к. слеш у последней папки в пути >ОС не ставит

Это зависит от операционной системы.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй спросить у службы поддержки, либо написать на их форуме.

```
chdir(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/add/');
require('text.html');
```

Comment: chdir() [function.chdir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/vol2/byethost14.com/b14_<индивидуальный_номер>/add/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/php_sessions:/tmp:/var/www/errors:/home/vol2/byethost14.com/b14_<индивидуальный_номер>/htdocs)
Что это значит?

Comment: Вернее не так). Я понимаю, что у php нет доступа к этой папке, но как это исправить? - Еще раз уточняю, что это на бесплатном хостиге. Или куда перенести файл с паролями, чтобы они  php был доступен, а снаружи нет?

Comment: Если файл с паролями для подключения к базе данных - то почему бы его не оставить в этой же директории.
1) Расширение поставить php и пароли прописать в переменные (как в большинстве CMS).
2) Дополнительно можно заблокировать доступ с помощью .htaccess.
3) Изменить права доступа к файлу.

Comment: Ну не знаю, мне кажется лопатить код из-за ограничений хостинга, как-то не правильно. Тем более, что после того, как я все обкатаю мне предоставят нормальный хост. Короче, мне легче поменять на другой хост.
1. Так и сделано.
2. Это я знаю, но опять придется менять стуктуру сайта и лопатить код.
3. Уже и так стоит 777 :)
Неужели тут никто не пользоватся  byethost.com никогда? Возможно кто-то знает альтернативы? Только без рекламы и с доменом.

Comment: Да переместите вы папку уже >`_`< Сделайте в начале скрипта, в главном конфиге

    <? define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); ?>

И подключайте файлы как большинство нормальных людей(`require ROOT.'/app/text.html'`). Хостинг кривой будет - просто в этот дефайн добавите нес-ко букв. Ну или сношайтесь дальше с относительными путями.

Comment: Тут уже больше из интереса )

Answer (score 0):

если у вас так и написано: require('..app/text.html'), то вероятно ошибка в отсутствии слэша

```
require('../app/text.html') // так правильнее.
```

Comment: Там есть слеш - это я опечатался. Я же говорю код на локальной машине работает.

Comment: страшно даже подумать от таких мыслей:

    eval(file_get_contents('имя файла'));

Comment: require_once

Comment: страшно даже подумать от таких мыслей: - ну куда мне было деться)
require_once - тоже не работает

Comment: А руками файл читается на хостинге по FTP ?

Comment: Через FTP вообще зайти на сайт не могу. Только из WEB-интерфейса получается(

Comment: Да, файл читается.